# How do I solve Xcode archive error method x in category [filepath] from conflicts with same method from another category?

Tags: xcode, archive, fastlane

When archiving my React Native project using fastlane on CircleCI, I get this error:

```
 ld: method '+UIDatePickerMode:' in category from /Users/distiller/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-afcitdfwjbmwxbbbhpiatfbfkjkg/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/myapp/BuildProductsPath/Staging-iphoneos/react-native-date-picker/libreact-native-date-picker.a(RNDatePickerManager.o) conflicts with same method from another category
⚠️  ld: method '-RNFBContainsString:' in category from /Users/distiller/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-afcitdfwjbmwxbbbhpiatfbfkjkg/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/myapp/BuildProductsPath/Staging-iphoneos/rn-fetch-blob/librn-fetch-blob.a(RNFetchBlobReqBuilder.o) conflicts with same method from another category
⚠️  ld: method '-RNFBContainsString:' in category from /Users/distiller/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-afcitdfwjbmwxbbbhpiatfbfkjkg/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/myapp/BuildProductsPath/Staging-iphoneos/rn-fetch-blob/librn-fetch-blob.a(RNFetchBlobRequest.o) conflicts with same method from another category
```

which causes my archive to fail:

```
Running script 'Bundle React Native code and images'
▸ Generating 'myapp.app.dSYM'
** ARCHIVE FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    PhaseScriptExecution Bundle\ React\ Native\ code\ and\ images /Users/distiller/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-afcitdfwjbmwxbbbhpiatfbfkjkg/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/myapp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/myapp.build/Staging-iphoneos/myapp.build/Script-00DD1BFF1BD5951E006B06BC.sh (in target 'myapp' from project 'myapp')
(1 failure)
[14:26:45]: Exit status: 65
```

In case it's relevant, my gym config is:

```
    gymOptions = ({
      silent: true,
      clean: true,
      configuration: ENV['BUILD_CONFIGURATION'],
      export_team_id: ENV['IOS_TEAM_ID'],
      export_options: {
        signingStyle: "manual",
        provisioningProfiles: { 
          ENV['IOS_APP_ID'] => ENV[profile_env_name],
          ENV['PUSH_INTERCEPTOR_BUNDLE_ID'] => ENV[push_interceptor_profile_env_name],
          ENV['WIDGETS_BUNDLE_ID'] => ENV[widgets_profile_env_name],
        }
      }
    }).merge(
      File.directory?("../#{xcworkspace}") ?
        {workspace: xcworkspace} :
        {project: xcodeproj}
    )
    gym(gymOptions)
```

and I'm using Xcode v13.4.1

Weirdly the same fastlane script is working for me locally.

Is there anything I can do to solve (or workaround) these errors?